# Robot Framework: Run Keyword If

Tags: robotframework

I have a scenario where i need to set a variable value based on the input.

If input is `'A'`, i need to `set ${var} = valA`

If input is `'B'`, i need to `set ${var} = valB`

So i have following code

```
${columnObject}=    Run Keyword If  '${sortBy}'=='A'    Set Variable    valA
${columnObject}=    Run Keyword If  '${sortBy}'=='B'    Set Variable    valB
```

I am getting `${columnObject}` as **None** if `${sortBy}` has value `'A'` as its also executing second statement and setting `${columnObject}`

Answer (score 3):

You can use the keyword `Set Variable If`

```
${columnObject}=    Set Variable If    '${sortBy}'=='A'    valA
...     '${sortBy}'=='B'    valB
```

`${sortBy}` will be assigned to `None` if neither of those conditions are met.